# Where does Deluge store active torrent files?

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

I had some torrent files downloading when I made fresh install after I backed up everything. So now files are incomplete and I want to find the former torrent files (.torrent) in my backup in order to add them again.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the [Deluge FAQ](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Faq#WheredoesDelugestorethe.torrentfiles):

```
~/.config/deluge/state
```

(The .config directory is normally hidden, but you can show hidden files in Nautilus by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.)

Comment: I know this is off-topic for AskUbuntu, but I found this post from Google, so here goes. For Windows users this is `%APPDATA%/deluge/state`.

Comment: Likewise, found this from Google. The directory on Mac OS is the same as in linux: `~/.config/deluge/state`.